# NFS4 works on one server but not the other

Tags: virtual-machines, nfs, share, nfs4

I have 2 VMs, both running debian buster. One is a test VM, the other my production file server. On both I installed the nfs server package through "apt install". I created a share on the test VM called nfs under `/mnt/nfs`. This folder is owned by nobody:nogroup. In my exports file I have the following content:

`/mnt/nfs        *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,insecure)`

There is no volume or harddrive attached to this "mountpoint" it is just a directory. When I mount this folder on another machine through `sudo mount -t nfs testVM:/mnt/nfs /mnt/disk` the volume is mounted as NFS4!!!!! This is what I want and it is awesome. (obviously the "other" machine contains the nfs-common package so I can mount the share in the first place)

Now to my issue. On my production file server, on which the same packages are installed, there are 6 volumes (raid partitions) mounted. They are managed by the host (proxmox virtualization environment) and passed through to the VM. I added which folder I wanted to share in the `exports` file and exported these folders through `exportfs -rav`. As an example, I have shared the following folder:

`/srv/test       *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,insecure)`

Which was supposed to be a test to see if I share a folder without anything attached externally what would happen. Unfortunately that does not work and every time I am trying to mount an nfs share as NFS4 the mount reverts back to NFS3.

Whatever I am trying nothing gets mounted to any other VM or any other machine, for that matter, as an NFS4 share. Everything is just shared as NFS3, which I don't want as NFS4 supports additional features that I need in order to make other stuff work in my network (especially file locking).

Does anybody have any ideas why I am unable to us a NFS4 from my test machine but not from my production file server?

Comment: How do you try to mount the share from your production server? Have you tried adding an explicit version while mounting (`-o vers=4.2`) and what is the result?

Comment: @SethosII sorry for my late reply and thanks for yours. I tried to mount a share just now with `sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4.2` and `sudo mount.nfs -o vers=4.2`. Obviously I used a mount that existed but I am getting the error `mount.nfs: mounting <IP>:/mnt/path failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ok, try with just `<SERVER IP>:/path` without `/mnt`. Sadly there is no way to list available NFS exports on the client with NFS4. Before NFS4 you could use `showmount -e <SERVER IP>`. But the `No such file or directory` points to something with the path and if I remember correctly NFS4 changed the way how paths are shown to the clients.

Comment: @SethosII But how should that work? the /mnt is part of the path. The share is at /mnt/volume6/kubedata.

Comment: NFS4 has a concept of a root for the exports. Depending on where this is set you need to leave out the preceeding path. See `fsid` in the manpage of `exports`. You could test to set `fsid=0` as an option to your export and mount with `IP:/` without any path as it will use the exported directory with `fsid=0` as the root.

Comment: @SethosII thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestions but unfortunately without success. I have added a "root" path to the exports file with `/mnt/volume6 IP(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure)` but that also only mounted as a nfs3 version. At this point I only see 2 options. 1 create a new VM and transfer all the disks and functionality to that new machine or 2 just accept that the existing VM does not allow a NFS4 share. Everything I tried so far will not work unfortuantely.